# Set timed delay for Bootstrap Hover menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some code that will enable my bootstrap menu items to display on hover instead on click. (I know its a little besides the point but its a customer requirement). It works fine but I want a slight delay instead of automatically displaying so that it won't be too annoying.

Here is my css:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
.navbar-nav .caret {
display: none;
}
.navbar-nav .open ul {
display: none;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
color: white;
background: none;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
color: #969696;
background: none;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .hovernav > a {
color: white;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .hovernav > a {
color: #969696;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .hovernav:hover > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .hovernav:hover > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .hovernav:hover > a:focus {
color: #333;
background: transparent;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .hovernav:hover > a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .hovernav:hover > a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .hovernav:hover > a:focus {
color: #fff;
background: transparent;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li:hover {
background: #e7e7e7;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li:hover {
background: #080808;
}
.navbar-nav .hovernav:hover > .dropdown-menu {
display: block;
}
}
```

And here is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function ($, window, delay) {

    var mq = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 768px)');
    if (mq.matches) {
        $('ul.navbar-nav li').addClass('hovernav');
    } else {
        $('ul.navbar-nav li').removeClass('hovernav');
    };

    if (matchMedia) {
        var mq = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 768px)');
        mq.addListener(WidthChange);
        WidthChange(mq);
    }
    function WidthChange(mq) {
        if (mq.matches) {
            $('ul.navbar-nav li').addClass('hovernav');
        } else {
            $('ul.navbar-nav li').removeClass('hovernav');
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use jQueryUI, you can add some more parameters to `.addClass` and `.removeClass` ([doc here](http://api.jqueryui.com/addClass/)).

It will animate your menu, and you can specify the duration of the animation.